# I'm getting an error when I try to register a module with sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm getting this error:

```
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1388:in `register': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

when I try to register an extension using either

```
context.send method, component
```

or

```
context.instance_eval "#{method} #{component}",__FILE__,__LINE__
```

1. context = `App < Sinatra::Base`
2. method = `:register`
3. component = `Sinatra::ModuleName`

Thing is doing the same thing with `helpers` works perfectly fine, it's only when I try to do it this way with an extension.

edit:

Here's the code block it's erroring at:

```
  def register(*extensions, &block)
    extensions << Module.new(&block) if block_given?
    @extensions += extensions
    extensions.each do |extension|
      extend extension
      extension.registered(self) if extension.respond_to?(:registered)
    end
  end
```

specifically  `@extensions += extensions`

Comment: I think you’ll need to provide more information about what is going on. `@extensions` shouldn’t be `nil`. How and where are you making this call, and why are you using `send` and `instance_eval`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After placing this:

```
base.instance_variable_set :@extensions, []
```

into the `self.inherited` hook of my class, the problem went away. I'm guessing due to the fact I'm not directly inheriting from sinatra and rather my own class, it (the instance variable) wasn't being created or somthing.

edit:

Ok, after poking around the sinatra code, I realise now that sinatra calls some code in it's own inherited hook that wasn't getting fired in my own. I simply call `super` (without `base.instance_variable_set`) in my inherited hook before my own code and now it's working!